# Add new column in the dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This a dynamic query and it is showing as a table. But I want to ad a column in this query as 'header' as identifier. The dynamic query is below:

```
SELECT [YR_4]
    ,[YR_3]
    ,[YR_2]
    ,[YR_1]
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN yr = 9999
                THEN 'A Medians'
            ELSE cast(yr AS VARCHAR(10))
            END AS yr
        ,yrdes
    FROM #years2
    ) AS t
PIVOT(MAX(yr) FOR yrdes IN (
            [YR_4]
            ,[YR_3]
            ,[YR_2]
            ,[YR_1]
            )) t1
```

Can somebody help me to add a column with hardcoded value in the above query?

Comment: Can you show the expected result

Comment: The expected result will be a table format which is already I am getting. Just I want to add new column in that. Thank u

Comment: What could do you want to add to this ?

Comment: The result is showing as a table so in that table I want to add a column with hardcoded value

Answer (score 0):

You can have a additional column with hardcoded value as given below:

```
SELECT [YR_4]
    ,[YR_3]
    ,[YR_2]
    ,[YR_1]
    ,'Hardcoded_value' AS AdditionalColum -- Code change here
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN yr = 9999
                THEN 'A Medians'
            ELSE cast(yr AS VARCHAR(10))
            END AS yr
        ,yrdes
    FROM #years2
    ) AS t
PIVOT(MAX(yr) FOR yrdes IN (
            [YR_4]
            ,[YR_3]
            ,[YR_2]
            ,[YR_1]
            )) t1
```

Comment: I tried this as you suggested above but it is showing error: Invalid Column Name "Hardcoded_value"

Comment: @karabimukherjee. . .  Use single quote to present literal string.

Comment: @YogeshSharma: Yes, I have used single quote

Comment: @YogeshSharma, thanks for correcting. Wrongly used double quotes. corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want sub-query :

```
select 'header' as custom_col, t.*
from ( <dynamic query> 
     ) t;
```

You can also use temporary table :

```
SELECT [YR_4, [YR_3], [YR_2], [YR_1] INTO #Temptable
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN yr = 9999
                  THEN 'A Medians'
                  ELSE cast(yr AS VARCHAR(10))
             END AS yr, yrdes
      FROM #years2
     ) AS t
     PIVOT ( MAX(yr) FOR yrdes IN ([YR_4], [YR_3], [YR_2], [YR_1] )
     ) t1;
```